# How to custom change the height of MUI Date Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<Box sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DatePicker
                    label="Enter Date"
                    slotProps={{ textField: { size: "small" } }} // want to add custom size
                    sx={{
                      width: "80%",
                      fontSize: "14px",
                    }}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </Box>
```

I want to find a way so I can change the height of mui datepicker's textfield height, no by using predefined props like size='small || large'

slotProps={{ textField: { size: "small" } }} tried this and simply style height, but it does not work.

I want to change height by passing 10px or 20px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sx` prop to achieve this!

```
<DatePicker
  ...rest of props...
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      size: 'small', // don't need this anymore so feel free to remove
      sx: {
        '> .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          height: 20 // whatever height you want here
        }
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

It is definitely worth noting that adding a custom height to the outlined input of the DatePicker isn't sufficient to achieve the look you probably want, because you'll have to play around with positioning the label depending on if you want it in the outlined input or not.

See more about this prop: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/